Facing issue while accessing file from private blob storage using AKS pods
we are using a service from AKS pods, one of the functionalities is to hit the azure translator service which is trying to access the file from the blob storage which Access level is set to private.
we have enabled all required private end points from Translator to blob, also added role assignments but still unable to access the file from blob. we are encountering below error:

{'id': 'xxxx-5d1b-4e20-8002-xxx', 'createdDateTimeUtc':
'2024-10-10T09:02:52.0829033Z', 'lastActionDateTimeUtc':
'2024-10-10T09:02:54.0855904Z', 'status': 'ValidationFailed', 'error':
{'code': 'InvalidRequest', 'message': 'Cannot access target document
location with the current permissions.', 'target': 'Operation',
'innerError': {'code': 'InvalidTargetDocumentAccessLevel', 'message':
'Cannot access target document location with the current
permissions.'}}, 'summary': {'total': 0, 'failed': 0, 'success': 0,
'inProgress': 0 , 'notYetStarted': 0, 'cancelled': 0,
'totalCharacterCharged': 0}}

we are using translator path as below using sas urls for source and destination URLs.
TRANSLATOR_PATH = "translator/text/batch/v1.0/batches"
API_ENDPOINT = ENDPOINT + TRANSLATOR_PATH
Not able to understand what we are missing still to access the files for translation from AKS pod. file upload is successful but accessing the files are being causing access issues. Help me out to resolve this issue.


'InvalidTargetDocumentAccessLevel', 'message': 'Cannot access target document location with the current permissions.'

The above error occurs when you don't have proper permission to access the target container in the azure storage account.
You can use the below sample code which generate SAS token and translate specific file from one container(English) to another container(Spanish) using python code.
Code:
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,generate_container_sas, ContainerSasPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests
import json

# Azure Blob Storage and Translator API credentials
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "venkat326123"
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY = "Txxxxx"
TRANSLATOR_ENDPOINT = "https://xxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
SUBSCRIPTION_KEY = "8xxxxxxx6"


# Containers and blob details
SOURCE_CONTAINER_NAME = "test"
TARGET_CONTAINER_NAME = "venkat"
SOURCE_BLOB_NAME = "testblob.txt"
TARGET_BLOB_NAME="sample.txt"

# Function to generate SAS token for a blob
def generate_container_sas_token(container_name,permissions,expiry_hours=1):
    sas_token = generate_container_sas(
        account_name=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
        container_name=container_name,
        account_key=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY,
        permission=permissions,  # Permissions for the container
        expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=expiry_hours)
    )
    return sas_token

def create_container_sas_urls():
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY)

    source_sas_token = generate_container_sas_token(SOURCE_CONTAINER_NAME, ContainerSasPermissions(read=True,list=True))
    source_blob_url = f"https://{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/{SOURCE_CONTAINER_NAME}/{SOURCE_BLOB_NAME}?{source_sas_token}"
    
    target_sas_token = generate_container_sas_token(TARGET_CONTAINER_NAME,ContainerSasPermissions(write=True,list=True))
    target_blob_url = f"https://{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/{TARGET_CONTAINER_NAME}/{TARGET_BLOB_NAME}?{target_sas_token}"
    
    return source_blob_url, target_blob_url

def create_translation_batch(source_blob_url, target_blob_url):
    translator_path = "translator/text/batch/v1.0/batches"
    api_endpoint = TRANSLATOR_ENDPOINT + translator_path

    headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': SUBSCRIPTION_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    body = {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "storageType": "File",
                "source": {
                    "sourceUrl": source_blob_url,
                },
                "targets": [
                    {
                        "targetUrl": target_blob_url,
                        "language": "es"  
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    # Print the request body for debugging
    print(json.dumps(body, indent=4))

    # Send the request
    response = requests.post(api_endpoint, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(body))
    
    # Print response details for debugging
    print(f"Response Status Code: {response.status_code}")


# Main function to execute the steps
def main():

    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY)   

    source_blob_url ,target_blob_ur = create_container_sas_urls()
    print(f"Source Blob SAS URL: {source_blob_url}")
    print(f"Target blob SAS URL: {target_blob_ur}")

    create_translation_batch(source_blob_url, target_blob_ur)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
Source Blob SAS URL: https://venkat326123.blob.core.windows.net/test/testblob.txt?se=2024-10-14T12%3A51%3A41Z&sp=rl&sv=2023-11-03&sr=c&sig=xxxxx
Target blob SAS URL: https://venkat326123.blob.core.windows.net/venkat/sample.txt?se=2024-10-14T12%3A51%3A41Z&sp=wl&sv=2023-11-03&sr=c&sig=xxxxx
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "storageType": "File",
            "source": {
                "sourceUrl": "https://venkat326123.blob.core.windows.net/test/testblob.txt?se=2024-10-14T12%3A51%3A41Z&sp=rl&sv=2023-11-03&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxx
            },
            "targets": [
                {
                    "targetUrl": "https://venkat326123.blob.core.windows.net/venkat/sample.txt?se=2024-10-14T12%3A51%3A41Z&sp=wl&sv=2023-11-03&sr=c&sig=xxxxxx",
                    "language": "es"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
Response Status Code: 202


Reference:

Use Document Translation APIs programmatically - Azure AI services | Microsoft Learn
How to fix "code":"InvalidDocumentAccessLevel","message":"Cannot access source document location with the current permissions." - Microsoft Q&A by Anand Prakash Yadav.


Thanks for your quick response Venkat. we are using the same code. but the translator service has been triggered from a AKS pod then it will try to access the file from private blob storage. then we are encountering this InvalidTargetDocumentAccessLevel error. we also tried to provide necessary access endpoints and also role assignment but still we are stuck with the same error

Which role you have given to access the blob storage?

Also,check whether you using correct credential?

we have provided Storage Blob Data Contributor role from translator; the same credentials are working properly if we use the blob as public.

Have you tried with SAS token which I mentioned above for both source and destination?

How are you creating SAS token in your environment??

Yes I was using sas token for both source and destination using
def generate_blob_sas_url(blob_name):
blob = generate_blob_sas(account_name=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, container_name=CONTAINER_NAME,
blob_name=blob_name, account_key=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY,
permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
expiry=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=45))
blob_url = 'https://' + STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME + '.blob.core.windows.net/' + CONTAINER_NAME + '/' + blob_name + '?' + blob
return blob_url.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This is resolved by using the source and target file paths without sas tokens as the private endpoint is been set and role assignments has provided.
